# *NgFor over custom JSON categories file not rendering

Tags: arrays, json, angular, http

I have this simple structure on my assets:

```
[
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "name":  "Fruits"
          },
          {
            "name": "vegetables"
          },
        {
          "name": "Meat"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

My Data Service (with two JSONS calls):

```
getCategories() {
    return this.http.get<any>('./assets/categories.json')
  }

getProducts() {
    return this.http.get<any>('./assets/products.json')

  }
```

Home TS (EDITED)

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataService.getCategories().subscribe(data=>{
  this.categories=data[0]['categories'] -> this works!!
  console.log(data)

}) 
this.dataService.getProducts().subscribe(data=>{
  this.products=data[0]['products']
  console.log(data)

})
```

}

Home HTML: (EDITED)

```
<div class="col-md-4" >
            <div class="list-group" style="color:black">
                <a 
                *ngFor="let c of categories"
                routerLink='/home'
                [queryParams]="{categories:c.name}"
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                [class.active]='categories===c.name'>
                    {{c.name}}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" >
            <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let p of products">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    {{p.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The logs are fine but the products JSNON isntnt displayed like the categories. Somehow I can't display the categories and continue the project. Is the JSON badly formatted? Am I calling it the wrong way? Can soneone give me a hint, please?

EDIT (@Michael D): Despite the categories JSON issue was solved, i cam up with another issue, but his second JSON has the same structure! I just don't see waht im'm missing. Here it is

The second JSON:

```
[
    {
    "products:": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Apple",
            "price": "free",
            "category": "Fruits"
        },



        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Grass",
            "price": "Free",
            "category": "Vegetabes"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "price": "Free",
            "category": "Vegetabes"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

SnapShot of both logs:
[image]

Comment: somehow its a junior question but hnnestly i'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `categories.json` doesn't directly contain the object, it rather contains an array with one element of property `categories` at parent level. Try the following

```js
this.dataService.getCategories().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.categories = data[0]['categories'];
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

**Update: `forkJoin` to combine observables**

If you were to subscribe to multiple observables simultaneously you could use RxJS `forkJoin` to combine them. I doubt this will solve the issue with `products` object, but it's more elegant and it wouldn't hurt the chances.

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

ngOnInit() {
  forkJoin({
    categories: this.dataService.getCategories(),
    products: this.dataService.getProducts(),
  })
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      // handle reponse
      this.categories = response.categories[0]['categories'];
      this.products = response.products[0]['products'];
    },
    error => { // handle error }
  );
}
```

**Update: `products.json` issue**

It appears there is a potential typo in the `products.json` file. The key is `products:`. Instead practically it would be `products`.

Comment: i have the exact same problem with another JSON. It doesnt make any sense because the sructure is the same and i aplied thae same response as you suggested!

Comment: Please post the JSON in the question.

Comment: I will Edit som for you

Comment: I don't see why it won't work. Do you get any error message or does the data doesn't get displayed?

Comment: Please see the data structure in the console log. Also perhaps you might need to move the `*ngFor` directive from the `<ul>` tag to `<li>` tag.

Comment: I changed the ngFor to the li and nothing. the logs and data structure are like i've posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214282/discussion-between-michael-d-and-mellville).